# Difficulty in deserializating list of object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I am trying to make a rest call to bankingClient application's getTrans() method from  AccountClient application, output returned will be List of Banking so in bankingClient app I made a BankingList pojo containing a field List of Banking and I am passing it to response type in rest template getForObject method but it is giving me error "Cannot deserialize value of type `com.p1.pojo.BankingList` from Array value"

This is the method in AccountClient which is making a call to BankingClient's "/banking/{ano}" mapping

```
@GetMapping("/listofTrans/{cid}")
public BankingList getTrans(@PathVariable Integer cid) {
    List<Account> a = acc.getByCid(cid);
    BankingList b=new BankingList();
    for(Account a1:a) {
        b = restTemplate.getForObject("http://BankingClient/banking/"+a1.getAno(),BankingList.class);
    }
    return b;
}
```

This is the method in Banking Client

```
@GetMapping("/{ano}")
public List<Banking> getTrans(@PathVariable Integer ano) {
    return service.getTrans(ano);
}
```

This is my Banking class with getters,setters and constructors

```
public class Banking {
    private int trn_no;
    private String dateOfTrn;
    private int ano;
    private double amount;
}
```

and BankingList class

```
public class BankingList {
    public List<Banking> list
    public List<Banking> getList() {
        return list;
    }
    public void setList(List<Banking> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }   
}
```

and the error I am getting is as follows

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.p1.pojo.BankingList` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1601) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1375) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1322) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:640) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:221) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:197) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3601) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar:2.12.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:378) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:342) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:105) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:334) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at com.p1.controller.AccountController.getTrans(AccountController.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

I am a beginner at this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace and the `com.p1.pojo.BankingList` class code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getTrans` API is returning just the array and not an object containing the array. So use `Banking[].class` as the type.

```
@GetMapping("/listofTrans/{cid}")
public Banking[] getTrans(@PathVariable Integer cid) {
    List<Account> a = acc.getByCid(cid);
    Banking[] items;
    for(Account a1:a) {
        items = restTemplate.getForObject("http://BankingClient/banking/"+a1.getAno(), Banking[].class);
    }
    return items;
}
```

You can use the ObjectMappers `constructCollectionType` method to construct the collection type and deserialise with that:

```
@GetMapping("/listofTrans/{cid}")
public List<Banking> getTrans(@PathVariable Integer cid) {
    List<Account> a = acc.getByCid(cid);
    List<Banking> items = new ArrayList();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CollectionType collectionType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Banking.class);
    for(Account a1:a) {
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://BankingClient/banking/"+a1.getAno(), String.class);
        items = objectMapper.readValue(response, collectionType);
    }
    return items;
}
```

But the simplest solution if you can update the `getTrans` API is to update it to return `BankingList` instead.

```
@GetMapping("/{ano}")
public BankingList getTrans(@PathVariable Integer ano) {
    BankingList list = new BankingList();
    list.setList(service.getTrans(ano));
    return list;
}
```